# Why is building causing an error while debugging and running the gradle are working fine

Tags: build-error, flutter-upgrade

```
C:\Users\ankit\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Failed to open output file 'D:\idm downloads\programs\i will source code\all\app codes\academylms-21\codecanyon-28805615-academy-lms-mobile-app-flutter-ios-android\Academy Lms Student Flutter Mobile App\academy_app\academy_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release\flutter_assets\packages/material_design_icons_flutter/lib/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf'. The parent directory may not exist, or the user does not have permission to create this file.

Failed to open output file 'D:\idm downloads\programs\i will source code\all\app codes\academylms-21\codecanyon-28805615-academy-lms-mobile-app-flutter-ios-android\Academy Lms Student Flutter Mobile App\academy_app\academy_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release\flutter_assets\fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf'. The parent directory may not exist, or the user does not have permission to create this file.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\ankit\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\ankit\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           50.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

tried flutter clean

How to build my apk file?